# How would I achieve this using SQL or BigQuery SQL. Aggregating different combinations of data across multiple columns

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, aggregate, analytics

Here is a [screenshot of desired output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbSV2.png) I'd like to be able to combine multiple columns and rows of array data into a single row of arrays, that combines any duplicates.

I've tried to unnest each row of arrays into multiple rows with individual items, then combine them but haven't had much luck. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each row has a common identifier - I assume from the screenshot that Views = 124 for all three rows, then STRING_AGG can be used to join the strings on the basis of this common identifier.

```
SELECT Views, STRING_AGG (breakdownOfViews,', ') , STRING_AGG (source,', '), STRING_AGG (medium,', '), STRING_AGG (site,', ') FROM table group by Views;
```

This works by combining all strings in separate rows to the one row where the identifier (in this case, Views) is common to both.